# WordPress widget to display more than one images in a frame or div

Tags: wordpress

Is there any word-press widget/plugin available which can switch images in a div or a frame automatically with a time interval. ?

My requirement is to have a div or a frame which can display images one at a time and move to the next image after a time interval automatically.

One of the similar example is the "Top News Section" in bbc website.(www.bbc.co.uk).

If there is no plugin from word-press, let me know whether this can be achieved by  java-script or i need to use some flash plugin for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a plugin than please have a look here.

http://5wpthemes.com/we-recommend/

Also from your wordpress dasboard, go to Plugins - Add New and search for desired plugin.